# iOS Share Extension's App Icon not showing up

Tags: ios

Recently I've written a share extension of my host app. Because of my confidentiality agreement, I can't give a specific icon picture of my app. But I can give a picture like below:
[image: The extension icon of my icon is the default developing icon.]

So, I'm pretty sure of my host app's icon is set. Why is my extension's icon showing nothing?
I've tried to create a new asset catalog in my extension and put an app icon in it. But it's still not working. Does anybody have a clue? I'll be so appreciated for the answer.